# How to get Response Header values in a SharePoint page using C#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, http-headers, guid

With the below code I am able to get the Response Header values for the key "Server" but not for "SPRequestGuid" or "request-id"

```
var headervalue = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers["Server"];
```

"headervalue" seems to be empty for "SPRequestGuid" and "request-id" but I can see these values using Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we cant capture the incoming response headers directly, we have to create a new request in the code and then we can capture the response header values for the created request.